# What are the permissible numbers for japa count that are less than 108?

Tags: mantras, japa

It is well known that when you do a mantra japa 108 is the minimum number of times you should do to get the wholesome benefit of the japa.Sometimes,a higher number ,1008, is also recommended.

But my question is,if there is so much scarcity of time that you can't even do the ideal number 108 then what are the other smaller numbers that are mentioned in the scriptures?

I know of 9,11,27 and 54.Is 60 a permissible number?I'm asking because i have a mala consisting of 60 beads.

Comment: @Anilkumar,no, i don't see it as a duplicate of the question you mentioned.I'm not asking about the significance of the number 108 here?i'm specifically asking for lesser numbers for japa count that are permitted in scriptures.

Comment: Answer varies from person to person. Ask your guru. Most malas given by gurus are 108...

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda I think you misunderstood my question.All my malas are having 108 beads only.Only one is having 60 beads.But that is not important.I want to know which numbers, less than 108 ,are permitted in our scriptures as valid japa counts.I mean we just can't do arbitrary numbers of japas like 13 17,56 or say 99.Can we?That was my first question and my 2nd question was whether the particular no 60 is a valid number or not.?

Comment: Again, varies from person to person. Ask your guru.

Comment: Related [What is the significance of '108' beads in the rosary (japmala)?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/877/3500). @Rickross changed.

Comment: I think 18is based on the number of chapters in Gita. dasavatara+ ashtakshara
108
pancharaatra samhiti
i am yet to decide for 28

Comment: 10 (dasha) & 28(ashta-vimshathi)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Current Sringeri Peethadhipati Jagadguru Shankaracharya Sri Ananta Vibhushita Bharati Teertha Mahaswami says in his [Anugraha Bhashanam](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3tsyqzMFsF8).

> The Shastras prescribe two pakshas: Mukhya Paksham and Gouna Paksham
>
> To do 1008 Gayatri Japam is Mukhya Paksham. People used to do this for
>   3 kaalas in the olden days.
>
> If there is not sufficient time, then the Shastras prescribe Gouna
>   Paksham of doing 108 Gayatri Japam.
>
> If there is further little time, then the Shastras prescribe doing at
>   least 32 Gayatri Japam.
>
> But people usually ask for an alternative and a way to leave
>   Sandhyavandanam. For that, there is no other alternative.
>
> For a person who has had Upanayanam and Brahmopadesham (according to
>   Shastras), he has to do Sandhyavandanam till the end.

Usually people say 10 Gayatri minimum but that is not valid as stated by Sringeri Jagadguru.

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 5):

As per [this](http://www.astrojyoti.com/mantras.htm) page the minimum number of chants is **3** & the other permisible numbers are **11,21,27 & 54**.So,in particular, **60** is **not** a valid japa count number .

> For mantra reciting, a lot depends on the type of mantra you intend to
>   recite and the purpose. Some people recite some mantras daily. It is
>   up to their convenience. The normal number of times a mantra is
>   recited is **3, 11, 21, 27, 54 and 108** or more.

Although the above info is generally valid but in some specific cases it does not apply.For example:

> For specific Graha shanti, the number of times the mantra to be
>   recited is prescribed. The prescribed time limit during which it
>   should be completed is one mandala or 40 days. You are given a grace
>   period of 8 days, taking into account any emergency or illness. So
>   maximum 48 days.

In Mahanirvana Tantra Lord Sada Shiva says

> The number of daily recitations can be 10,108 or 1008.

From the 7th Chapter, verses 76-81:

> Sandhya, whether Vaidika or Tantrika should be performed thrice daily,
>   and according as the worship changes so does its service (76). The
>   worshippers of the Brahma-Mantra have performed their Sandhya when
>   they have made japa of the Gayatri, realizing within themselves the
>   identity of the Gayatri and Brahman (77). In the case of those who are
>   not Brahma-worshippers, Vaidika Sandhya consists of the worship of and
>   offering of oblations to the Sun and the recitation of the Gayatri
>   (78). O Gentle One! **In all daily prayers recitation should be done one
>   thousand and eight or a hundred and eight or ten times** (79). O Devi!
>   the Shudras and Samanyas may observe any of the rites proclaimed by
>   the Agamas, and by these they attain that which they desire (80). The
>   three times of performance (of Sandhya) are at sunrise, at noon, and
>   at sunset (81).