# What are permissible number of chanting japa/mantra? Whats its reason?

Tags: mantras, japa

Scripture reference for these numbers

What is its science, Is chanting 10 times less effective than chanting 9 times..

Should mantra/japa to be chanted number of time (say 3) in one sitting?

Which is more effective..

Chanting in one sitting or chanting with time gaps in between chants..but keeping counts..

lets take number 3..

Which is more effective

a) Chanting Mantra Daily Once For 3 Days.. so chanted 3 times; days taken 3

b) Chanting Mantra 3 times in Single Day with time gaps..like 1hr/2hr etc gap in 
between chant.. so chanted 3 times; days taken 1

c) Chanting Mantra 3 times in one sitting.. no time gaps between consecutive chants

It is said that number needs to be quadrapled in kaliyuga.. Is it True?

Can someone list permissible numbers in Ascending Order.

Comment: @Rickross ^^^^^

Comment: Looks like duplicate of: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10499/what-are-the-permissible-numbers-for-japa-count-that-are-less-than-108

Comment: You can also check the answer here: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/36971/how-many-times-aditya-hridayam-stotra-should-be-recited-in-one-sitting/36982#36982

Comment: 10 (+8=18), 100 (108) and 1000 (1008) are the counts with 10 being adham (worst) and 1000 uttam (best).

Comment: @Rickross I read those answers before posting Q.. 10 being adham (worst).. what about 3,9... 10 (+8=18)..why add 8.. In Q among a)b)c) which is effective.. Any scripture reference for these numbers.

Comment: @Rickross Whats the reason for these numbers... I thought that; (practice makes perfect) so, the more number of times someone chants mantra, his mantra pronouciation becomes clear, he becomes more devote,, so mantra becomes  effective.... So the maximum number of times chanted is the best..

Comment: So why there is number,, in allowed counts,, after 108 comes 1008... Is chanting 150 times less effective than chanting 108 times.