# My daughter wants to know what's with 12, 21, 48, 108 numbers

Tags: worship

Since as per Hinduism, the above are auspicious numbers.

After I told my daughter to do namaskara 12 times, and I told her I am reciting a certain small prayer 108 times each day for 1 mandala (48) days, etc, she is questioning me. What would be the right answer?

Comment: https://www.stephen-knapp.com/108_the_significance_of_the_number.htm

Comment: Related https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/14306/12071